# Variable value is not recognized

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script to get MS Office licenses from remote computers:

```
$DiskLetter = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert Disk Letter: '
$computers = gc "$DiskLetter\ComputerList.txt"
foreach($computer in $computers )
{
    write-host $computer
    Invoke-Command -computername $computer -scriptBlock {cscript "$DiskLetter\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus}
}
```

The reason I have to insert a disk letter is that the script is run from an USB drive and the system assigns first free letter to it, which is different on every system.

But my question is - why the $DiskLetter variable in the second part of the script:

`{cscript "$DiskLetter\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus}`

does not work? If I assign an actual drive letter - it works.

I've already tried to set a global variable:

`$global:DiskLetter = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert Disk Letter:`

and invoke it like this:

`Invoke-Command -computername $computer -scriptBlock {cscript "$global:DiskLetter\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus}`

but it still does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Change `$DiskLetter` to `$using:DiskLetter` - this will cause PowerShell to copy the local value of `$DiskLetter` to the remote session

Comment: Thank you, it works. So apparently even a global variable does not transfer to a remote session. Good to know.

Comment: I can see why that might be confusing at first, but "global" really means "process-global". Remote sessions necessarily run in separate processes :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, the remote session is like an independent sandbox. What was also surprising for me after applying the solution, was that the path has to be present on remote computer, not on the local machine. This is different for me, because when I was using Windows' PSEXEC command (with -c switch), it copied the local file to the remote machine first and executed it from there.